# Install Entensions Locally

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I know that whenever we add or remove extensions Chrome will add and delete them in the Extension IDs file in /.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/IDs_filefolder (in Linux in my case). So can we legally install extensions locally by copying our unpacked extension folder into the Extensions file folder?

I tried to copy the whole unpacked source extension to the path but nothing happens when I run the chrome browser.

Comment: What makes you hate clicking "Load unpacked" on `chrome://extensions` ?

Comment: My purpose is to install extensions automatically by local unpacked source.

Comment: No. The only way is to hack it by patching `Secure Preferences` file and recalculating its hashsum.